# Nested IF clauses not parsing as I expect

Tags: excel, vba

I've got this piece of code in a module, intended to write a line of data to an output sheet in one of three ways. The *idea* is to calculate the number of items that can be stacked per layer, then (in `CheckRTs`) write it to the output. If the category is either "N/A" or "SELECT" it should skip the output section.

What's actually happening is that it seems to be parsing the `GoTo NoStack` line every run, whatever the value of `sCategory`.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
If sCategory = "Plates" Then
    If dWidth > wsSorter.Cells(iSrcLine, 19).Value / 2 Then iLayerQty = 1
    If dWidth <= wsSorter.Cells(iSrcLine, 19).Value / 2 Then iLayerQty = Int(wsSorter.Cells(iSrcLine, 19).Value / dWidth)
Else If sCategory = "N/A" Or sCategory = "SELECT" Then
    GoTo NoStack
Else
    If dWidth > wsSorter.Cells(iSrcLine, 19).Value / 2 Then iLayerQty = 1
    If dWidth <= wsSorter.Cells(iSrcLine, 19).Value Then iLayerQty = Int((wsSorter.Cells(iSrcLine, 19).Value - dStanchion) / dWidth)
End If

Do
CheckRTs:
    If IsEmpty(wsRTTrack.Cells(iRTCount, 1)) = False Then
        WriteLine
    ElseIf IsEmpty(wsRTTrack.Cells(iRTCount, 1)) = True Then
        MakeNewRT
        GoTo CheckRTs
    End If
Loop While iQty > 0

NoStack:
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx: `Else If` should be `ElseIf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing space between fist `Else` and `If` to make `ElseIf`. If you do it like you did there, you'd have start new `If` within the `Else` with it's own `End`
Nested If's aren't the easiest to debug, in this example `Select Case` should make things slightly easiesr, so you could consider using it instead.

Comment: I've seen Select Case mentioned before - I'm still fairly new to VBA - so I'll look it up and try it out, cheers.